# android nougat edittext cursor is not aligned in start. it always shoing me to the centre at the hint

Tags: android, user-interface, android-7.0-nougat

i have a login screen, which is having two EditText, everything is working fine but when i run the app in android nougat 7.0.1 the cursor of login screen is showing in center. I have also tried with the solutions provided here..but not working for nougat device

```
<com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:hint="@string/emailEditText"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorEditTextHint"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:digits="@string/digits_email"
                app:layout_heightPercent = "6.5%"
                app:layout_paddingBottomPercent="2.25%"
                app:layout_textSizePercent="2.22%"
                android:text="">
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
```

Comment: Add your XML code along with Java code.

Comment: @W4R10CK added the xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the attribute `android:textAlignment` from `EditText` :

```
     <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"             // added
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"    //added
        android:layout_gravity="start"       //added
        android:hint="text"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="131dp" />
```

Comment with added are new, add only 3 attributes to your xml.

Comment: @W4 ...thanks buit now hint is showing in the left ..how do i make hint in centre ...tried google it but it tends me to the same position where i was.. curser in between hint text....please suggest me something sir,,

Comment: You can't make the hint gravity center and text from left. Both attributes can't work together at the same time. Either it will be left or center. Consider accepting answer if helped. :)

Comment: yes agree ! ... in all devices its working fine.. so  we wont consider nougat. :)